# Manage/unmanage character copying (char sets)

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, character-encoding

I have a C# dll that accesses a database (all strings are Unicode). My c++ unmanaged code is multibyte. When I get/copy strings from C# to C++ I'm doing the following.

System::Collections::Generic::List^ imageCodes;

```
    p->imageCode =((std::string)(const char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(imageCodes[i]).ToPointer());
```

I'm worried about DBCS codes (Asian, etc).

Also someday the C++ will be Unicode and in that case how would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Handling Unicode strings in C++ is not impossible, it supports wchar_t and std::wstring.

Comment: If and when we move to UNICODE std::string would become std::wstring, that is a given. We would no longer use StringToHGlobalAnsi() but what would we do, just a straight copy? Thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx